# Swift 4 - Catch Error if Value not in Plist

Tags: swift, macos

I have this code

```
let path = self.userDesktopDirectory + "/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist"
        let dictRoot = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        if let dict = dictRoot{
                try print(dict["AppleLocale"] as! String)
        }
```

If the Value "AppleLocale" didnt exists the script crashes. What I must add to "catch" the Error and avoid the crash?

Comment: You only need to remove force unwrap i.e `print(dict["AppleLocale"] as? String ?? "AppleLocale does not exists")`

Comment: Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the Value "AppleLocale" didnt exists the script crashes. What I
>   must add to "catch" the Error and avoid the crash?

depends on what's the reason for causing the crash. Mentioning that "If the Value `AppleLocale` didnt exists" means the the reason for the crash would be the force casting:

```
dict["AppleLocale"] as! String
```

probably, it has nothing to do with the `try`, it would be:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Means that at some point `dict["AppleLocale"]` could be `nil` or even if it contains a value as not a string it will crash (*[optional](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330)*). You have to make sure that `dict["AppleLocale"]` is a valid (not `nil`) string, there are more than just one approach to follow for doing it, for instance you could do *optional binding*, like this:

```
let path = self.userDesktopDirectory + "/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist"
let dictRoot = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
if let dict = dictRoot{
    if let appleLocale = dict["AppleLocale"] as? String {
        print(appleLocale)
    } else {
        // `dict["AppleLocale"]` is nil OR contains not string value
    }
}
```

Actually, I would assume that you don't have to deal with `try` for such a case.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot!

Comment: @Sascha7777 Glad to help. If this answer resolved your issue, please don't forget to accept it (green tick it) :) FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.